# How to use Liquibase-MongoDb-Spring-boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, liquibase

I checked and found that `liquibase` is extended for Mongo DB but I cannot see any example of using it with `spring-boot`, can anyone suggest the way to use `liquibase` with `spring-boot` for `mongodb`.
Any example would be helpful.

Comment: you should be able to use the normal liquibase:

https://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app

with the mongo db liquibsae driver
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase.ext/liquibase-mongodb/4.1.1

I am also looking at it, so if you have any findings let me know, also if I will have a working poc I will write an answer

Answer (score 6):

[Liquibase doesn't support MongoDB](https://www.liquibase.org/get-started/databases), but [they provide an extension to support MongoDB.](https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/spaces/CONTRIB/pages/1281163265/MongoDB+Extension) you can see more details [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/database-setup-tutorials/mongodb.html).
There are some prerequisite to be followed:-

- At least using liquibase version 4.0.0 or latest one.
- Add the [mongo-java-driver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver) dependency.
- Add the [Liquibase extension](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase.ext/liquibase-mongodb) dependency.

Take into consideration, This way has a different syntax than we usually used with other DB like Postgres or SqlServer DBs.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.0.xsd
      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

<changeSet id="1" author="bob">
    <ext:createCollection collectionName="myCollection">
        <ext:options>
        {
        validator: {
            $jsonSchema: {
                bsonType: "object",
                required: ["name", "address"],
                properties: {
                    name: {
                    bsonType: "string",
                    description: "The Name"
                    },
            address: {
                bsonType: "string",
                description: "The Address"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            validationAction: "warn",
            validationLevel: "strict"
            }
            </ext:options>
        </ext:createCollection>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find any documentation on Liquibase support for MongoDB apart from this github repo: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-mongodb.

There is this one - mongock.io which is similar to how Liquibase work and can be easily integrated with Spring boot. Below is the github URL:
https://github.com/cloudyrock/mongock

Comment: I agree with Yazik, mongok is more comfortable than liquibase when declaring changeset programmatically in java.

Answer (score 3):

Suggest you to use NoSQL support data migration library such as [mongock](https://www.mongock.io/). It provide data migration most of time like liquibase. mongock provide migration class instead of liquibase XML or JSON.

Comment: Athough with good intention. Your answer is not related to the question.